# ASP.Net Core2.0 with Windows authentication how i add column which will give me username of creater of element

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I created asp net core application(MVC) with Windows authentication.
How can i add option or column which is giving information about who created element. Am i doing this in model or in cshtml page ?
For example my model is

```
 public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller ( create )

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: TestModels/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Description,CreatedBy")] TestModel testModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(testModel);
            testModel.CreatedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(testModel);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'element'?

Comment: I mean, if im in create page of that model and i will create one element of it. Index.cshtml will display to me only Description from model he wont give me information about who created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a property to store name of user, that creates `TestModel` instance like this:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then, on controller action  that creates and stores  instances of `TestModel`, you need to fill this property like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestModelsController : Controller
{
    ...

    public TestModel Create(int id, string description)
    {
        var testModel = new TestModel { Id = id, Description = description };
        testModel.CreatedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;

        // store model (EntityFramework, etc...)
        // dbContext.TestModels.Add(testModel);
        // dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return testModel;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you have store element creater name in TestModel.CreatedBy.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but  can you check my code is it correct or no ?

Comment: You can ignore `CreatedBy` property when binding model: `public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Description")] TestModel testModel)`. Also you need to decorate your controller, or atleast your Create action with `[Authorize]` attribute for authentication to work (in case when you allow anonymous authentication on your host).

Comment: Got it, how can i implement somethingl like( about  who last modified by and date of motified :) ?

Comment: same way as we add `CreatedBy`, but now fill them in `Update` method of controller